# How to temporarily disable redirection from http to https in nginx?

Tags: nginx

The configuration file is configured to redirect http -> https. Tell me what I need to change in the file so that the site can be accessed both by http and https at the same time.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name first.com www.first.com;
    return 301 https://first.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name www.first.com;
        include snippets/ssl-first.com.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
        return 301 https://first.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        include snippets/ssl-first.com.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;                
        ...
        ...
```

}

Comment: A rough way to do it would be to change the redirect which is in the first block. Not knowing how everything is set up, this could be dangerous but try... Change that block's redirect line to: `return 301 http://first.com$request_uri;` restart nginx and see if it works

Comment: @Javier Larroulet, Maked this, but redirect is worked yet

Answer (score 0):

```
server_name first.com www.first.com;
```

should be replaced by

```
server_name www.first.com;
```

Then after # SSL configuration, add:

```
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
```